# Jquery animation and case random event

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, case

i make this script, but dont like work.  I tested a single case, and all work good, but when i put in switch mode, mouse stop it detection, and work sometime, and animation start simultany in the same time case 1: and case2:  ....

```
function muovi(){
var caso = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1);
alert (caso);
switch(caso){
case 1:
//go on and stop to see me
$(".vola").css("background-image", "url(img/gif/sx.gif)");
$(".vola").animate({"left": "+=300px"}, 10000);
setTimeout(function(){$(".vola").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/fr1.png)")}, 10001);  
setTimeout(function(){$(".vola").animate.stop()}, 10002);
case 2:
//go back and sto to see me
$(".vola").css("background-image", "url(img/gif/dx.gif)");
$(".vola").animate({"left": "-=300px"}, 10000);
setTimeout(function(){$(".vola").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/fr1.png)")}, 10001);  
setTimeout(function(){$(".vola").animate.stop()}, 10002);
}
}
```

this is a css:

```
.vola{
    background: url(img/sprite/sprite1dx.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    height: 61px;
    width: 31px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

and this, the htlm place of interesting:

...
div class="vola"  onClick"muovi();"> 
...
idk what make, for me its difficult to understand becouse case1 and case2 work in the same time O__O

Comment: `.animate` should be `.animate()`. Having said that, `$('.vola').stop();` should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your `case` statements were missing `break;`s.

```
$(function(){

    $('div.vola').on('click', function(){
        return window.muovi();
    });

    window.muovi = function(){
        var caso = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1);
        alert (caso);
        switch(caso){
            case 1:
                //go on and stop to see me
                $(".vola").css("background-image", "url(img/gif/sx.gif)");
                $(".vola").animate({"left": "+=300px"}, 10000);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".vola").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/fr1.png)");
                }, 10001);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".vola").stop();
                }, 10002);
            break;
            case 2:
                //go back and sto to see me
                $(".vola").css("background-image", "url(img/gif/dx.gif)");
                $(".vola").animate({
                    "left": "-=300px"
                }, 10000);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".vola").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/fr1.png)");
                }, 10001);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".vola").stop();
                }, 10002);
            break;
            default:
                alert('Hello?');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your jQuery wrapped in `$(function(){ ... });`. Updated my code above to include this. See above.